# Receiving Refresh Token from Windows Live SDK in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, live-sdk

I'm developing an universal windows app (Windows 10) where I have a "Two-Layered" App: On IoT-Devices (e.g. Raspberry Pi 2) it just displays content, but on all other Devices (PC, Notebook, Smartphone, etc.) you have something like an controller for the displayed data.

One of the features I want to realize is the Windows Live Login in the Controller Part to get Calendar Information in the Display-IoT-Part. For that I give users the opportunity to login with Windows Live as shown below:

```
LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.calendars", "wl.offline_access" });
if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    //Save the AccessToken from loginResult.Session.AccessToken
    TokenHandler.Save(loginResult.Session.AccessToken); //AccessToken is quite accessable right here
    //But as far as I know I should save the RefreshToken, but the Session has no field for it
}
```

So my proplem is, that I don't get a field from the **LiveConnectSession** where the **RefreshToken** could be stored, but all articles I read are telling, that I just need to add **wl.offline_access** to the scopes for receiving an RefreshToken.

I'm not very familiar with *OAuth2.0* and SDKs / APIs are building on OAuth, so does someone knows anything, what I'm doing wrong or how I have to handle it?

I'm really thankful for all well meant and helpful answers!

PS: I'm using the Live SDK 5.6 and not the new OneDrive API, because it has no access to Calendar Information

Comment: No one with an idea?

Comment: If you take a look at [the source of liveSdk](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows), then you will see that on most of executing request, the `RefreshTokenIfNeeded()` method is called. Therefore I think refresh token is not exposed, as it's handled automatically.

Comment: I've installed Live SDK 5.6.3 from nuget package, and there loginResult.Session has RefreshToken property, so not sure what is that you use where there is no such property.

Comment: @Evk: Could you please post your sorce coude? What project type do you use?

Comment: Simple console app as I remember, .NET 4.5. No specific source code, just in my case  loginResult.Session has both AccessToken and RefreshToken properties. Installed package via nuget, as I said.

Comment: @Evk In Windows Store app you won't see refresh token, because there is conditional compilation witch switches off refresh token `#if !WINDOWS_STORE`.

Answer (score 2):

> wl.offline_access

in this case it's talking about user authorization and allowing the app to have the user's authorization to work when they're not present (when the user is offline, instead of the computer/device).
This doesnt mean the app would login user when system is offline but would request user to allow app to work when user isn't present.
Even I had used the Live SDK to fetch user data in one of my earlier projects and but for calendar had to use Office365. Now you can even make use of [Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations)
Though we do get Access Token using loginResult.Session.AccessToken but I dont think a refreshToken is generated for WinRT app.